Assign action is not enabled in the asset browser
I created a character and added an animation.
I registered the character in the Asset browser and also registered the animation.
Characters are brought in well.
But the action isn't working well.
I checked if the bone name was different, and it was the same.
Press apply pose to activate the pose that connects to the first frame.
But the animation doesn't play.
The assign action button is active in the file that created the asset.
However, when I create a new file and try to import characters and apply poses, assign action is not enabled.
Why can't assign action be activated?

